# jquery find children selector performance

Tags: jquery, find, children

Is there a better way to write this. I'm checking the input of a textarea and trying to find if it contains an object or iframe tags, if not then set var x =1

```
if ($textareaval.find('iframe').length > 0) {
    alert('iframe')
} else if ($textareaval.find('param').length > 0) {
    alert('object')
} else {
    var x = 1;
    alert(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care which one it has you could combine the two checks into one:

```
if ($textareaval.has('iframe, param').length > 0) {
    x = 1;
}
```

**Edit:** You say you do care, though, so then no. Your code is fine, no improvement needed.

Comment: I need to know if it's iframe or embed, so i can grab it's attr accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

i think even you don't need to check length > o..
do like this..

```
if ($textareaval.has('iframe, param').length) {
   alert('iframe, param')
}else{var x=1;}
```

Comment: this really should be a comment imo.

Comment: if iframe i want to do certain things and if param i want to do other things, this doesn't give the flexibility without writing extra code. The way i have it work, i was just wondering if there is a simpler way to write it

Answer (score 1):

Observing that you will only be giving one alert, and therefore assuming that you will only encounter one type, I suggest the following:

```
    var foundItems = $textareaval.has('iframe, param');
    var alertVal = 1;
    if(foundItems.length){
       alertVal = "object";
       if(foundItems[0].tagName == "iframe")
          alertVal = "iframe";
    }
    alert(alertVal);
```

This has the advantage of only one traversal and minimal short-circuit logic utilizing the most common properties of the two objects tested. And, it's readable.

Note: the foundItems.length test is NOT testing for existence, as this property will always exist on a javascript collection; but, if it evaluates to 0, that is a false - and any other number is not.